# Getting flow error when running flow from a community page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, lightning-flow-builder

I am getting a weird issue when running a flow from a community page getting Flow navigation error but i am not getting any issue when running the same in debug mode.

In community page i am running the flow as different profile user and in debug mode also i am logging as other user and executing the flow but i am not getting error. Not sure why i am only getting in Community Page.

My flow has two screens, which are built using Lwc and embed in flow. After entering data on first screen, on clicking continue button on first screen navigating to second screen and on the second screen i have a edit button where on clicking edit button it should take me to first screen with data whatever enter earlier. All this working when working on debug mode but when running in a community page  on clicking edit button the page keeps on spinning it never land on the first page. when checking in consol.log i could see an error saying something related to flow navigation.

**Error:"Uncaught(in promise)Error.An internal server error has occurred Error ID:950015248-1954571(413121610) at Object.handleNavigationError(flowRuntimeV2.js.20) at eval(flowRuntimeV2.js.5) at eval(runtimeLib.js.1)**

Thanks,
Venkata

Comment: One other thing is when i create debug log for that user i don't get the error it runs smooth in Community Page and once delete the debug log the error repeats again

Comment: This looks like an internal GACK! I did check the internal GACK system and this an issue that requires a support case. Please raise an issue with Salesforce support with GACK details and repro steps!

Comment: Hi @VamsiVeguru I have a similar problem with screen flow on the community page.
Please help me if you had resolved it.